# 'Use the cfg File' tutorial last command unclear

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. Working through the tutorials in sequence. Following the last section 'Use the cfg File' on this page I edited CMakeLists.txt and added the following at line 13:

```
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
  cfg/Tutorials.cfg
)
```

Ran `$ ~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make` and this did a build with no errors.

When I ran `$ rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui -s reconfigure`, the gui opens but is blank and is missing any fields similar to that shown at the end of the tutorial page - http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile

When I then add the rest of the CMakeLists.txt entries listed in the section 'Use the cfg File' ...

```
// make sure configure headers are built before any node using them
add_dependencies(server dynamic_tutorials_gencfg)
```

... I get this build CMake Error:

```
CMake Error at dynamic_tutorials/CMakeLists.txt:18 (add_dependencies):
  Cannot add target-level dependencies to non-existent target "server".

  The add_dependencies works for top-level logical targets created by the
  add_executable, add_library, or add_custom_target commands.  If you want to
  add file-level dependencies see the DEPENDS option of the add_custom_target
  and add_custom_command commands.
```

The tutorial is not clear on how to use `add_dependencies()` in CMakeLists.txt i.e. is tells the reader ...

```
// make sure configure headers are built before any node using them
add_dependencies(example_node ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
```

Does anyone know how to use this command correctly to get the server.py node show correctly in the gui?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209926/%27use-the-cfg-file%27-tutorial-last-command-unclear/) by [andrewwi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22489/andrewwi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had this problem when I was adding dynamic reconfiguration to a project of mine.

Make sure that the add_dependencies line is AFTER the line that declares the library or executable that the dependencies refer to. In my file, the relevant lines are :

```
## Declare a C++ executable
add_executable(cloud_segmenter src/CloudSegMain.cpp src/CloudSeg.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
add_dependencies(cloud_segmenter ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
```

If they are the other way around, CMAKE tries to add dependencies to an executable or library that hasn't been declared yet, which is why it says the target is non-existent.

---

Originally posted by [ams](https://answers.ros.org/users/25160/ams/) with karma: 16 on 2015-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0